# How could I transform matrices on a list into igraph on a list by loop?

Tags: r, for-loop, igraph, network-analysis

When I use the for loop by R to simultaneously transform many elements (each one is a matrix) on a list to `igraph` objects by the function "graph.incidence", the code below is used and executed:

```
storage2 <- list()
count_1 <- 1

for (i in 1:57) {
    storage2[[count_1]] <-  graph.incidence(storage1[[i]], mode = c("all"))
    count_1 = count_1 + 1
}
```

However, when I check the list "storage2", the error message popped up:

> Error in if (is.na(no)) no <- len : argument is of length zero

How could I solve this problem? How could I transform matrices on a list into `igraph` on a list by loop?

Comment: Are you sure that `storage1` really has ok matrices for 1 through 57? A full running code-example would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This solution makes graphs from matrices inside lists. Maybe you could avoid a loop. I provide a code example using both `lapply()` and a loop below.

Note that your loop has two counters: `i` and `count_1`. For the example above you don't need both, but only:

```
for (i in 1:57) {
    storage2[[i]] <-  graph.incidence(storage1[[i]], mode = c("all"))
}
```

A full code-example would be useful, but I think you should verify that `storage1` really contains ok matrices.

In case you do need the loop, your approach with a counter is commendable. Were you to append to the list inside the loop, `storage2 <- c(storage2, graph.incidence(...)` would be less clean and potentially much slower since `c()` copies the entire list at each iteration resulting in an exponentially longer execution time.

I hope this code could help you move forward.

```
# Some setup
library(igraph)
dimensions <- 10
networks <- 5

# Example data of a list of random matreces:
storage1 <- lapply(1:networks, function(x) m <- matrix(sample(c(0,1), dimensions^2, replace=T), nrow=dimensions))

# lapply()-solution: Make networks from each list-item in storage1
storage2 <- lapply(storage1, 'graph.incidence')

# forloop-solution: Since you specifically want to do it in a for-loop, this is one way to achieve that
storage3 <- list()
for(m in storage1){
  storage3[[length(storage3) + 1]] <- graph.incidence(m)
}

# A quick test to see that the lapply-solution in storage2 is the same
# as the loop-solution in storage3
lapply(1:length(storage2), function(x) E(storage2[[x]]) == E(storage3[[x]]) )
```